# Determine payment based in the number of adults, number of children, and some combo box selection

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I shorten this code with a while loop? Is it possible? `cboFrom` and `cboTo` is a combobox. I only know how to do simple while loops and I feel like it's a waste of time to write all the indexes and values of the combox down

```
public int pay;      
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TheValue;
    int Matatanda = int.Parse(Adults.Text);
    int Bata = int.Parse(Children.Text);
    int Total = Matatanda + Bata;
    if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0) { TheValue = 1000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 1) { TheValue = 2000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 2) { TheValue = 3000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 3) { TheValue = 4000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 4) { TheValue = 5000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 5) { TheValue = 6000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 6) { TheValue = 7000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 7) { TheValue = 8000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 8) { TheValue = 9000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 9) { TheValue = 10000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 10) { TheValue = 11000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 11) { TheValue = 12000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 12) { TheValue = 13000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 13) { TheValue = 14000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 14) { TheValue = 15000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 15) { TheValue = 16000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 16) { TheValue = 17000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0) { TheValue = 1000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 1) { TheValue = 2000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 2) { TheValue = 3000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 3) { TheValue = 4000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 4) { TheValue = 5000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 5) { TheValue = 6000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 6) { TheValue = 7000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 7) { TheValue = 8000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 8) { TheValue = 9000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 9) { TheValue = 10000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 10) { TheValue = 11000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 11) { TheValue = 12000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 12) { TheValue = 13000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 13) { TheValue = 14000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 14) { TheValue = 15000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 15) { TheValue = 16000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
    else if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 16) { TheValue = 17000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

First of all - you have awful duplication of payment calculation `pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2;` you do this in each row. Move calculation to the bottom of method:

```
if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0)
else if
else if
//..

pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2;
```

Next - nothing is changing when you change `cboFrom` selected item. These lines are completely identical

```
if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0) { TheValue = 1000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; }
if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1 && cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0) { TheValue = 1000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; }
```

So you can move `cboFrom` selected index out of this code:

```
if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex != 0 cboFrom.SelectedIndex != 1)
    return;

if (cboTo.SelectedIndex == 0) { TheValue = 1000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; }
//...
if (cboTo.SelectedIndex == 16) { TheValue = 17000; Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; }
```

Now let's look what changes when `cboTo` selected index is changed. It's only `TheValue` value. It changes from `1000` to `17000`. Which is

```
 TheValue = (cboTo.SelectedIndex + 1) * 1000;
```

Now bring all together. You don't need loop:

```
 if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex != 0 cboFrom.SelectedIndex != 1)
    return;     

 if (cboTo.SelectedIndex < 0 || 16 < cboTo.SelectedIndex)
    return;

 int TheValue = (cboTo.SelectedIndex + 1) * 1000;
 int Matatanda = int.Parse(Adults.Text);
 int Bata = int.Parse(Children.Text) * TheValue / 2;   
 int Total = Matatanda + Bata; // NOTE: value is not used 
 pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2;
```

I would suggest you to check if your controls have integer value before parsing text (`int.TryParse`), separate UI logic from business logic and assign to your comboboxes some objects which have `TheValue` value. So that you will be able to use it directly without checking indexes. You should create some class with appropriate name:

```
public class Foo // use appropriate name
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then define display and value members of this class for combobox and after that assign collection of `Foo` objects as combobox data source (I use array just as example):

```
cboTo.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboTo.ValueMember = "Value";
cboTo.DataSource = new[]
        {
            new Foo { Name = "First value description", Value = 1000 },
            new Foo { Name = "Second value description", Value = 2000 },
        };
```

Now getting of selected value is simple as:

```
if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex < 0 || 1 < cboFrom.SelectedIndex)
    return;

int matatanda;
if (!int.TryParse(Adults.Text, out matatanda)
    return; // and show error

int bata;
if (int.TryParse(Children.Text, out bata)
    return; // and show error;

int value = (int)cboTo.SelectedValue;
bata = bata * value / 2;
pay = (value * matatanda + bata) * 2;
```

Also it would be nice if you'll explain in code why only `0` and `1` are appropriate values for `cboFrom`. Something like

```
 bool insuranceSelected = cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 0 ||  cboFrom.SelectedIndex == 1;
 if (!insuranceSelected)
     return;
```

Comment: I think you should check if `SelectedIndex` isn't `-1` too in case nothing is selected.

Comment: @t3chb0t agree, without datasource it might have value `-1`

Comment: I don't get why he uses `SelectedIndex` anyway. Wouldn't it make for more sense to use [`ComboBox.SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) and use an actual value instead?

Answer (score 2):

@SergeyBerezovskiy has shortend your `if`s very nicely so I'd like to just add that you might consider using an array for the values instead of directly using this calculation:

```
int TheValue = (cboTo.SelectedIndex + 1) * 1000;
```

As long as you know that there won't be other values it's ok but if you think some of them might change an array could help:

```
private int[] _values = 
{
    1300,
    2045,
    3000,
    // other values...
}
```

For now you can however generate all the values:

```
private int[] _values = Enumerable.Range(1, 18).Select(x => x * 1000).ToArray();
```

and get them later:

```
int TheValue = _values[cboTo.SelectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an over-simplification of a bigger function? Because you could replace that whole If-ElseIf block (both of them) with a simple function, if the example is a "real" representation:

From example:

- cboFrom has no effect on "TheValue" (and thus, the rest). 0 or 1, TheValue result is the same.

  - cboTo == 0: TheValue = 1000
  - cboTo == 1: TheValue = 2000
  - cboTo == 2: TheValue = 3000
  - ...
- The rest of the function is all copy/pasta. EVERY branch has this same block:

  - `Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2;`
- Total is unused

So, you have a *simple pattern* and lots of *duplication*.

**Simplified Provided Example:** So all you really need to do is add one to cboTo's index, multiply by 1000 and then do the rest of the function (based on the sample code):

```
public int pay;      
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check for SelectedIndex between 0/1 and 0/16
    if (cboFrom.SelectedIndex < 0 and cboFrom.SelectedIndex >  1) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    if (cboto.SelectedIndex   < 0 and cboTo.SelectedIndex   > 16) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

    int Matatanda = int.Parse(Adults.Text);
    int Bata = int.Parse(Children.Text);

    int TheValue= (cboTo.SelectedIndex + 1) * 1000;
    Bata = Bata * TheValue / 2; 
    pay = (TheValue * Matatanda + Bata) * 2;
}
```

**Another Option:**
If the "real" code is more complicated, and From actually affects the outcome... I would probably look into generating an array automatically (as t3's answer) or manually:

```
int[,] array = new int[2, 17];
array[0,0] = 1000;
array[0,1] = 2000;
...
array[0,16] = 1800;
array[1,0]  = 1000;
...
int TheValue = array[cboFrom.SelectedIndex, cboTo.SelectedIndex];
...
```

**Input Verification:**
Also, you might want to verify that the [int.Parses](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse) are successful.

```
int Matatanda;
bool MatatandaResult = int.TryParse(Adults.Text, out Matatanda);
if (MatatandaResult == false) { throw new ArgumentException; }
```

**Number Rounding:**

Not sure what the goal is, but do you want Bata to round up? Down? Does it not matter? What is the expected outcome when `Bata * TheValue / 2` resolves?

Right now, it's all integer math. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299094/c-how-do-i-do-simple-math-with-rounding-on-integers) for examples. Integer math truncates on the `/2` - it doesn't "round" up for .5 if that's what you are expecting. Just something to consider.